# .prop("disabled", true); ,prop("disabled", 'disabled'); and .attr('disabled', 'disabled') is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, model-view-controller

I have following and trying to disable the radio buttons, its not working in chrome but works in IE

```
<div id="MBOption" class="col-lg-12" style="display:inline-block; align-content:center">
                @*<input type="radio" name="MBOptn" id="DisMB" value="DisMB" checked />*@
                @if (ViewBag.UserPref == true)
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="MBOptn" id="DisMB" value="DisMB" onclick="DisplayMB();" checked />
                    <label for="DisMB">Display Medical Bills       </label>
                    <input type="radio" name="MBOptn" id="NoMB" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divMBDeleteModal" value="NoMB" onclick="NoMB();"/>
                    <label for="NoMB"> Do not display Medical Bills</label>
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="MBOptn" id="DisMB" value="DisMB" onclick="DisplayMB();"/>
                    <label for="DisMB">Display Medical Bills       </label>
                    <input type="radio" name="MBOptn" id="NoMB" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divMBDeleteModal" value="NoMB" checked />
                    <label for="NoMB"> Do not display Medical Bills</label>
                }

            </div>
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript code?

Comment: $("#MBOption").prop("disabled", true);

Comment: Well you are disabling a div element, not inputs....

Answer (score 1):

Disable the inputs, not the parent div

```
$("#MBOption input").prop("disabled", true);
```